# How to set initial value in v-select when using infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have it set up just like in [the official example](https://vue-select.org/guide/infinite-scroll.html) ... but the user's choice is stored in the DB, and the next time they go to the page I want it to be pre-set to their previous choice. I can't seem to figure out how to do it in this case, since the `:options` is a computed property...

**EDIT:** I did not provide enough of my code... I updated it with more info... I did find the issue, it was two things (1) the data in `prefs` was not in the same format as the data in `paginated`, so it could not identify the initial value, and (2) I was not using `v-model` but rather `@input` because I need to send the choice to the database. By setting up `v-model` to a dummy data variable and filling that variable with the data from `prefs` in the same format as the options list, then it worked. I will post my answer also.

HTML

```
  <v-select
    :options="paginated"
    :filterable="false"
    @input="setValue"
    @open="onOpen"
    @close="onClose"
    @search="(query) => (search = query)"
  ></v-select>
```

JS

```
...
  props: ['prefs'],
...
  data: function() {
...
    countries: []
...
  computed: {
    filtered() {
      return countries.filter((country) => country.includes(this.search))
    },
    paginated() {
      return this.filtered.slice(0, this.limit)
    },
    hasNextPage() {
      return this.paginated.length < this.filtered.length
    },
  },
...
  methods: {
    setValue: function(v) {
      this.prefs = v.id;
      (... ajax call to update database ...)
    }
...
  created: {
    (... ajax call to populate this.countries from database ...)
  }
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, what's the issue?

Comment: `prefs` will not go on `props` but in the `data:function() { return {prefs} }` when you fetch from your ajax you update `this.prefs = [What user choice]`

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/chauriya/pen/BaZOxby

Please look at the attached [pen](https://codepen.io/chauriya/pen/BaZOxby), Here I'm setting a default value to v-select with v-model, I see your `prefs` is a prop, if you are passing default value to `prefs` then it should set in v-select. If you are sending some default value in prop then please update your question it will be more clear than.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was twofold:

1. I was not using `v-model` but rather `@input` because I wanted to send the choice to the DB in an AJAX call, so there was nothing for the initial value to hook onto.
2. The data in `prefs` was not in the same format as the data in `paginated` (string vs. object) so it could not locate the initial selection in the options list.

Here I post the fixed code:

HTML

```
<v-select
    :options="paginated"
    :filterable="false"
    v-model="dummy"
    @input="setValue"
    @open="onOpen"
    @close="onClose"
    @search="(query) => (search = query)"
  ></v-select>
```

JS

```
...
  props: ['prefs'],
...
  data: function() {
...
    countries: [],
    dummy: {}
...
  computed: {
    filtered() {
      return countries.filter((country) => country.includes(this.search))
    },
    paginated() {
      return this.filtered.slice(0, this.limit)
    },
    hasNextPage() {
      return this.paginated.length < this.filtered.length
    },
  },
...
  methods: {
    setValue: function(v) {
      this.prefs = v.id;
      (... ajax call to update database ...)
    }
...
  created: {
     let me = this;
    (... ajax call to populate this.countries from database ...)
    .then(function(resp) {
        me.countries = resp.data;
        me.dummy = me.countries.find(c => c.id == me.prefs);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Now that I have it working it occurs to me it is worthless when the options list is huge - is there a way to do it like SELECT2 where it gets the list a page at a time and search text is sent to the server to filter the paged list?